# Auto Refresh Title Webpage from PHP file result

Tags: javascript, php, refresh, title, titlebar

I have a php file that generates a value from database and I want that value to be constantly displayed on the website in the title box.

I tried:

```
   <script>
 function autoRefresh_title()
 {
     $.post("currentbank.php").done(function(response){
     document.title(response)

  setInterval('autoRefresh_title()', 1000); 
            </script>
```

The code above goes in the index.php file and currentbank.php is:

```
<?php
@include_once ("set.php");
$game = fetchinfo("value","info","name","current_game");
echo round(fetchinfo("cost","games","id",$game),2);
?>
```

PS: set.php is just login info

Comment: Please make sure the question is complete (you are missing quite a few closing braces in the code provided). And you should aslo provide a brief info when the code is failing (assuming that it does not work for you since you are asking here).

Comment: You edited the question only partly, the javascript code is probably still incomplete (or incorrect as mentioned by @Akshay).

Comment: document.title is not  a function

Answer (score 2):

```
document.title(response);
```

change to:

```
document.title = response;
```

Comment: I think that your script do not work, because it contains errors. Try this: `<script type="text/javascript"> function autoRefresh_title() { $.post("currentbank.php", function(response) { document.title = response; }, 'text'); } setInterval(autoRefresh_title, 1000); </script>`

Comment: Did you check the browser console? I think that you have JS error.

Comment: Can you give the link of your page?